# How to get the actual path of a referenced .dll file from the current working assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I have to create objects for a particular class at runtime, the classes should be configured in the app settings of the web.config file, using Reflection.

The problem is, I am not able the Load the assembly. Since the classes are in the referenced dlls. I am not able to get the actual path of the referenced dll.
I Have tried Path, CodeBase, Current Directory. Can someone help me??

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly is referenced by the project, you don't need to load it. You can get it by getting the Type of a class which is in that particular assembly.

In general, doing Late-Binding on your own, isn't the best of an idea. We had some issues with that at our project and it's quite a lot of work to do it right. You could instead use some of the many different IoC-Containers, which will find the assembly and also the class for you.

**EDIT:**

I was maybe a bit confused, that I didn't think of it earlier. You can simply load an Assembly by it's name. Than it should find the assembly in all the referenced paths or the GAC.

Further information can be found [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx)

Comment: actually I have to create objects for different classes based on the function parameter. Using this parameter as a key, will get the class name from the value of appsettings. Then should load that assembly, get that particular class and use CreateInstance to create object @zahorak

Comment: The dlls are not shared. They are private. So I am not able to load the assemblies